# Вопрос по настройке сети KVM на Debian 11

Tags: сеть

Есть два роутера, между подсеть 192.168.2.0 с 30-ой маской, на первой роутере поставил интерфейс enp4s0, ip - 192.168.2.1, маску 255.255.255.252, шлюз - 192.168.2.1. На втором роутере поставил интерфейс enp4s0, ip - 192.168.2.2, маску 255.255.255.252, шлюз - 192.168.2.1. Пинг с роутера 1 на интерфейс 192.168.2.2 не ходит, в обратную сторону тоже нет, в чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключение идет через Hypervisor, к роутерам подключился с помощью VNC Viewer.

Доп. вопрос, я так же все еще не настроил Ip-tables, это может на что то влиять?

Comment: я бы использовал 32 маску. а по пингам - что там с марщрутами?

Comment: Маршруты - мосты?

Comment: Какие мосты? Маршруты по `ip r l`